# Page reachable if user connected or not.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am currently working on a website with MVC5 and Identity.

I have a page which is reachable when a user is connected (with an account) but also when he is not. If he is connected I want to display some information .

If he is not connected I want to display less information and I want to invite him to log in.

I don't know how to implement such a page. I have this controller :

```
   [Authorize]
    public class PController : Controller
    {
        private int UserId;

        public ActionResult Index(int userId ) {
            UserId = Convert.ToInt32(((ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).FindFirst("test").Value);
            PModel model = new PModel(UserId);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

and my model :

public class PModel {
    public int UserId { get; set; }

```
public PModel(int userId) {

    ........
    }
```

In both cases, I would like to call the Index method, and do the processings according to the connexion in the model :

```
  public PModel(int userId) {
      if(userConnected) {

         } else {

         }
  }
```

I don't know whether it's possible like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do this in your model (typically). If you want to use the default forms authentication model that comes with ASP.net, you need to set it up in your web.config and provide appropriate login/logout actions etc.  In the config, you have something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="30" name=".MySite" protection="All"/>       
</authentication>
```

The `Authorize` attribute on your action will stop the code within that method from running if the user is not authenticated.  The forms authentication code will redirect the user to the 'loginUrl' specified in your web.config if they come directly to a page in your site without logging in.

---

From your comment, I have misread your question.  You will need to remove the `Authorize` attribute altogether then, and you can set your model `userConnected` property based on the `Request.IsAuthenticated` property in the controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to directly redirect the user. He can view my page even if he is not authenticated ; just the information in the page will be different. I want only one page, but with different content depending on whether the user is authenticated or not.